# How to create a single query with multiple where columns and value are optional

Tags: filter, where-clause

for example,
select * from a where id=@id and date between @date1 and @date2
when i passed  @id=1 @date1='09/29/17'and @date2='09/30/17'
then an output is correct

When I passed @id=0 (means no id found in a table) @date1='09/29/17'and @date2='09/30/17' then output comes between date and ignore id column

means I want the filters like a shopping website

Answer (score 0):

The way that you would accomplish this would be to use an OR on the ID column, to leave your SQL looking like:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE (@id=0 OR id=@id)
  AND date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

The thing you need to be careful and aware of using this type of approach is that depending on your DBMS you will likely end up in a scenario where the execution is optimized for whatever the first execution path took.  If it's a very big table, this could end up causing problems.